# compute Expectation Propagation messages for sum

Tags: bayesian

Can anyone help me in understanding how Expectation Propagation updates are computed when we have a function on several variables? 
Like this example: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/infernet/docs/How%20to%20add%20a%20new%20factor%20and%20message%20operators.aspx
This is a sum function. But for EP, we should have a factorized term. So how these mean and variance for each element in this sum is computed?

Comment: Can you explain to us what is EP?

Comment: Sorry I edited my post. It's Expectation Propagation for Bayesian learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updates on that page come from belief propagation (a special case of EP).  The general formula for belief propagation messages is:
$$
m_{a \rightarrow i}(x_i) \propto \int_{\mathbf{x} \backslash x_i} f_a(\mathbf{x}) \prod_{j \ne i} m_{j \rightarrow a}(x_j) dx_j
$$
For the sum factor, $f_a(\mathbf{x}) = \delta(x_c - \sum_{i \ne c} x_i)$ where $x_c$ is the child of the factor and the rest are parents.  $\delta$ is the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).  The messages $m_{j \rightarrow a}$ are Gaussians.  If you let $i=c$ then you get the downward message on that page, otherwise you get the upward message.