# Message passing (belief propagation) in practice - observed variables

Tags: graphical-model

In a graphical model with variables with continuous distriubtions, and some observed variables, how can I compute the messages to be passed?
I know the messages but I don't know how to implement it?
For continuous variables, and also for observed ones? Can anyone introduce a source which has the theory and an example implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Expectation propagation is what you are looking for. BP is a special case of EP where variables are discrete.

Comment: But what about loopy belief propagation? Is that discrete too?
The formula of message passing in this page:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/infernet/docs/How%20to%20add%20a%20new%20factor%20and%20message%20operators.aspx
It is said that updates come from belief propagation:
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121180/compute-expectation-propagation-messages-for-sum
So belief propagation seems to have a continuous representation. Also I don't understand this continuous case (EP or BP) for observed variables case. How we integrate observed variables in the model?

Comment: Here also we can see there exists variants of for example Gaussian Belief Propagation:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belief_propagation